# Apache - match file in all directories

Tags: apache, wildcard, .htpasswd

Looking for some guidance on how I can match a specific file in a wildcard of directories.

Example - the rule needs to apply to:

```
/path/to/folder1/directory/index.php
/path/to/folder2/directory/index.php
/path/to/folder3/directory/index.php
```

Here is an example of the configuration made.  The idea is to ensure that they are prompted for a username/password if this file is accessed:

```
<FilesMatch "/path/to/*/directory/index.php">
AuthName "Login"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
```

require valid-user

However, that doesn't seem to be working.

**EDIT**

After the first answer response, I changed the code.  The primary purpose of this is to ensure that if anyone accesses the administrator/index.php file, they are asked for username and password via mod_security.  Any other index.php files recursive to the administrator directory should not be prompted:

```
<Directory "/location/to/.*/administrator">
    <Files "index.php">
    AuthName "Login"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Does that do the trick?

Comment: yes, your edited example should work, but in this case you don't need `.*` but `*` - without a `~` (or without DirectoryMatch), wildcards use globbing, not regular expressions. It can be a bit confusing...

Comment: Got it.  That does work.  One more issue though - you have to actually put in the /index.php in the URL for the prompt to ask for the username/password.  Any way to also make it prompt if they just type in website/administrator/ as well?

Comment: you could just put the auth direvtives directly into the directory section, omitting the file directive, then the whole administrator directory should require a password. shouldn't make much difference for the use case.

Comment: Got it.  Just put that in there and will see if that works OK.  Thank you Mata.

Answer (score 0):

Like the [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files) directive, the [`<FilesMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) directive operates only on the basename of the file, not on the complete path, so specifying a path name wont work.

Other then that, `FilesMatch` uses regular expressions by default (`<FilesMatch "expression">` is basically the same as `<Files ~ "expression">`), so `"path/*"` would actually match `path` followed by an arbitrary number of slashes, what you ment would be `"path/.*"` - but like I said, paths don't work with `FilesMatch` and `Files`.

But the directives already apply to all subdirectories, so if you put a `.htaccess` file in the common base directory, it will apply to all subdirectories (unless it's overridden later):

```
<Files "index.php">
    ...
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That would require quite a bit of work to make a .htaccess file in all directories.  That is why I was looking to create one catch-all rule in the actual apache server config.  In essence, I am wanting to require a username/password for anyone that accesses the administrator/index.php file for Joomla on any website on the server.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to combine [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) to set an environment variable if the path matches with [Allow from env=...](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) - at least if you don't have access to the server config. otherwise a `<Directory ...>` directive shoudl do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Mata.  I run the web servers so I have full access to set the web server config.  That is exactly what I'm trying to do - make a universal requirement.